# How can I convert this hook based code to class based code? is it possible?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

How can I convert this hook-based code to class-based code? Does the code still work?
I'm using a react/ASP.net Core template. My project consists of several components that are siblings.
I'm trying to send a state from a component to another one.

```
import { useState } from "react";

//the change is reflected in the ImageEditor component
const ImageEditor = ({ yourState }) => (
  <p>State in the ImageEditor = {yourState}</p>
);

//ImageTile changes the state through the setYourState method
const ImageTile = ({ yourState, setYourState }) => (
  <button onClick={() => setYourState("World!")}>
    Change State from the ImageTile
  </button>
);

//App is the parent component and contains both image editor and tile
const App = () => {
  //the state which holds the image ID is declared in the parent
  const [imageId, setImageId] = useState("Hello");
  return (
    <div>
      <ImageTile yourState={imageId} setYourState={setImageId} />
      <ImageEditor yourState={imageId} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

You can see the complete code on:

https://codesandbox.io/s/billowing-brook-9y9y5?file=/src/App.js:0-775

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried converting? What happened when you tried? Did you get an error? What error? Can you post your atempt?

Comment: I haven't any experience related to props. When I make a state in Parent, it will pass as a prop to the child. Now I want to give this value. This confuses me! this is my first project. Just remind the example is not my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'll need to declare the state in the parent:

```
state = {
  someKey: '',
};
```

And then in the parent, define some function to update it:

```
updateSomeKey = (newValue) => {
  this.setState({ someKey: newValue });
}
```

And then pass both of these values as props to your sibling components:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Sib1 someKey={this.state.someKey} updateSomeKey={this.updateSomeKey} />
      <Sib2 someKey={this.state.someKey} updateSomeKey={this.updateSomeKey} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

You shouldn't need to in order to update the 'shared' state. In the code above, the someKey state can be updated in either component by calling the updateSomeKey function that is also available as a prop.
If either component calls that function (this.props.updateSomeKey('hello!')) the updated state will propagate to both components.

Answer (score 0):

A parent passes it’s state to a child via props. The child is not allowed to change its parents state, if a child wants to change a parents state then the parent passes a callback to the child that the child can call to change the state. This is fundamental to reacts state management. A child does not need to know how a parent stores it’s state (class instance, hook instance or state library).

if your application uses a global state manager like redux, then global state is mapped to props and a store action can be called to update global state. In this case the child does not need to know who else is using the state because it’s global.

```
class Foo extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { myState: 0 };
    this.setMyState = this.setMyState.bind(this);
  }

  setMyState (value) {
    this.setState({
      myState: value
    });
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <MyChildCompoent myStat={this.state.myState} setMyState={this.setMyState} />
    );
  }
}
```